# sample with replacement from a unique list

Tags: r, random

It feels like I can't be the first to ask this, but I can't find anything similar. Maybe I have the wrong key words.

I have a dataset where one individual repeatedly occurs (A)

```
k <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D")
```

Now, I want to randomise k from that same group with replacement, but I want each observation to have an equal chance of being selected - i.e. I want to sample from a unique list of k observations.
My understanding is that if I use replacement =T, ~50% of my random samples would = A because ~50% of the sample from which to choose = A.

How can I even the odds in a new column = ki, without getting the error that k & ki must be the same length.
i.e.

Error: Problem with mutate() column ki. ℹ ki = sample(k$unique(d$k), replace = T). ℹ k must be size 287358 or 1, not 118

Cheers, and sorry if I've missed something.

Comment: Why not just sample from `unique(k)`?

Comment: Because in R, I get an error telling me that the length of unique k (4) must match the length of k (7). ----   Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `ki`.
ℹ `ki = sample(k$`unique(d$k)`, replace = T)`.
ℹ `k` must be size 287358 or 1, not 118.

Comment: Try `mutate(ki = sample(unique(k), n(), replace = T) )`

Comment: Please show the code you use that produces that error. `sample(unique(k), size = n(), replace = TRUE)` should work just fine. Put the code in the question so people don't have to read through comments to understand the question.

Comment: Also don't use `data$column` inside `mutate`. dplyr verbs expect unquoted column names without any `data$` prefix.

Comment: I'm sorry - jdobres's answer worked perfectly.